# How set convert Images inside an ImageList to Icon Type?

Tags: c#, winforms, image, icons

I have a few icons inside an ImageList in a GUI application. I want to set the notification icon from this list but the problem is it accepts only Icon instances not Image.

```
System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon trayIcon = ...;
System.Windows.Forms.ImageList notifierImageList = ...;

trayIcon.Icon = notifierImageList.Images[0]; //This fails since no such cast exist
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a couple of options.

1. Instead of storing the icon in an ImageList, you can store it as a resource.  Then construct an Icon object from the resource.
2. Convert image to icon by creating a handle.  This one I found on the web.

   ```
   notifyIcon1.Icon = Icon.FromHandle(((Bitmap)imageList1.Images[0]).GetHicon());
   ```